# Best way to deploy Excel Workbook that uses MySQL database?

Tags: c#, mysql, excel, c#-4.0

I am creating Excel 2010 workbook project in C#(.NET 4.0 frmw) using VS2010. This Excel workbook is my work interface. It contains a few buttons through which i call some user controls and forms, or they do some other functional tasks, ... . Also, this workbook uses data from MySQL database. Communication with this database is currently well while  database is on localhost.

My question is, and I need your opinion on, what is(or will be) the best way to deploy this application so that it runs on users machines and with database on server machine?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deployed Using Windows Installer. Here is an example:

http://clear-lines.com/blog/post/create-excel-2007-vsto-add-in-msi-installation.aspx

Worked for me, normally, with few modification on my own.

Answer (score 0):

Hope all the user machines are on the same network.

You can change the `ConnectionString` to point to your current  DB and deploy it.

Link for Connection String for MYSQL http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql

which will be `Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;`

Comment: Yes, they are. Connection to db is not one of my possible problems and will not be, but deploying this application on user machine.

I'm interested in your opinion on how to deploy this kind of application.

however, thank you on this note about connection.